# Links in images in photoshop?

Tags: image, hyperlink, photoshop

I don't think this is possible, but is there any way you can put a link in an image? I'm not talking about HTML. Literally in an image. Maybe when you put text in Photoshop there is a way to make that text a link? I don't know.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In terms of *standard* image formats (.bmp, .gif, .jpg, .png, etc.), I'm pretty sure that's not supported **in** the image in the way you want. The best way I can think of doing it would be to put the link in the metadata ([Wikipedia link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata)).

Comment: Do you mean that the link should be clickable and followable from within Photoshop (which isn't a browser)? Or from within some other application?

Comment: I would like the link to be clickable within a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1

Press "C" to select the Slice tool. Choose a slice style in the Options bar. In the default Normal mode, you click and drag on your document image area to create slices. Enter numeric proportions to create a height-to-width ratio for the Fixed Aspect Ratio style. Note that these values don't represent actual dimensions. To enter specific slice measurements, choose "Fixed Size" style.

### Step 2

Click and drag on your document to create slices. If you've added guide rules to your image, click on the "Slices From Guides" check box in the Options bar so Photoshop automatically creates slices following your guides.

### Step 3

Press "Shift-C" to switch to the Slice Select tool. Because it's nested with the Slice tool and shares the same keyboard shortcut, you need to use a modifier key to cycle from tool to nested tool.

### Step 4

Double-click on the slice to which you want to assign the URL, opening the Slice Options dialog box. Type or paste your URL into the URL data-entry field, using either relative or full URL format. A relative URL loads a location that's within the site that contains the link. An absolute URL starts with "http://" and includes the full link to a page, which usually loads from another website.

### Step 5

Specify a page-loading location in the Target entry field. To open a new browser window for the page you're loading, enter "_blank" without the quotation marks. To replace the current page content with the new page, enter "_self" without the quotation marks.

### Step 6

Generate the HTML code that underlies the link you added. Open the "File" menu and choose "Save for Web & Devices" to access Photoshop's optimization and export capabilities. Once you choose image output settings and click on the "Save" button, you enter the Save Optimized As dialog box. Set the Format to include HTML in your file export and select HTML options.
 read more @ [link1](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-hyperlink-photoshop-55217.html) [link2](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/add-photoshop-53701.html)

Comment: Thats not what I want. I don't want to make the actual image clickable. I want to make text inside an image clickable.